# Java Weblogic application in eclipse using tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, weblogic

I am trying to find tutorials for java web logic applications that use eclipse as IDE for development.
I have failed to found a tutorial for beginners. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, Weblogic and Tomcat are both Java EE containers. How do you intend to use both?

Comment: Hum, ok so basically weblogic is the oracle server like tomcat is the apache server?

Comment: Almost. Weblogic is a full Java EE application server, Tomcat only meets the "Web Profile"; unless you add a few things... like [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/).

Comment: Thank you, i edited the question to suit better what i need. Do you know any tutorial?